# Drives Disappear when Turning off Raid

Tags: windows, boot, bios, raid

I have a Dell Workstation T7610 with a 256 gig SSD and a 2 TB HDD. When I try to disable the raid controller the drives disappear in the boot order. How can I keep the drives active without having them have to go through raid? It has an LSI controller

Comment: Your RAID controller is the thing controlling your SATA ports, try putting your HDD's in SATA ports not attached to the raid controller.

Answer (score 3):

If the disks are attached to the RAID controller, than disabling it will cause the drives to disappear - even if they're not in a RAID configuration. RAID controllers are just disk controllers with extra hardware support for if you want to configure the disks into RAID.

If you don't want the drives to use the LSI controller, then you need to connect them to a different controller. Note, even if they are not connected to the RAID controller, disabling the RAID controller will cause them to show up differently to the system, and depending on how the system is set up that *may* cause it to become non-bootable until the bootloader is updated, but the disks will still show up in the BIOS.